# UIViewControllers in ContentView of UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I don't want to use page control because i have to change the button when the user scroll horizontally.

So I am  using UIScrollview and container view.

By following [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content) 
I am able to add child view controller in container view but the scroll view does not scroll with auto layout.

Here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.array_pageContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

CallViewController *objGameReviewPageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CallViewController"];
[self addChildViewController:objGameReviewPageContentViewController];
UIView * view = objGameReviewPageContentViewController.view;




HomeViewController *objHomeViewController= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
[self addChildViewController:objHomeViewController];
UIView * view1 = objHomeViewController.view;





GroupViewController *objGroupViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GroupViewController"];
[self addChildViewController:objGroupViewController];
UIView * view2 = objGroupViewController.view;




CallenderViewController *objCallenderViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CallenderViewController"];
[self addChildViewController:objCallenderViewController];
UIView * view3 = objGroupViewController.view;




CasesViewController *objCasesViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CasesViewController"];
[self addChildViewController:objCasesViewController];
UIView * view4 = objGroupViewController.view;




[self.scrollViewContent setPagingEnabled:YES];
[self.scrollViewContent setScrollEnabled:YES];
[self.scrollViewContent setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:YES];
[self.scrollViewContent setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
[self.scrollViewContent setDelegate:self];




    [self.array_pageContent addObject:view];
    [self.array_pageContent addObject:view1];
    [self.array_pageContent addObject:view2];
    [self.array_pageContent addObject:view3];
    [self.array_pageContent addObject:view4];


NSInteger pageCount = self.array_pageContent.count;

self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
self.pageControl.numberOfPages = pageCount;

self.mutableArray_pageContentViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < pageCount; ++i) {
    [self.mutableArray_pageContentViews addObject:[NSNull null]];
}

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

CGSize pagesScrollViewSize = self.scrollViewContent.frame.size;
self.scrollViewContent.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pagesScrollViewSize.width * self.array_pageContent.count, pagesScrollViewSize.height);

[self loadVisiblePages];
}

- (void)loadPage:(NSInteger)page {
if (page < 0 || page >= self.array_pageContent.count) {
    return;
}



UIView *pageView = [self.mutableArray_pageContentViews objectAtIndex:page];
if ((NSNull*)pageView == [NSNull null]) {
    CGRect frame = self.scrollViewContent.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0.0f;

    UIView *newPageView = nil;
    newPageView = [self.array_pageContent objectAtIndex:page];

    newPageView.frame = frame;
    [self.scrollViewContent addSubview:newPageView];
    [self.mutableArray_pageContentViews replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:newPageView];
}
}

- (void)purgePage:(NSInteger)page {
if (page < 0 || page >= self.array_pageContent.count) {
    return;
}

UIView *pageView = [self.mutableArray_pageContentViews objectAtIndex:page];
if ((NSNull*)pageView != [NSNull null]) {
    [pageView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.mutableArray_pageContentViews replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:[NSNull null]];
}
}

- (void)loadVisiblePages {
CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollViewContent.frame.size.width;
NSInteger page = (NSInteger)floor((self.scrollViewContent.contentOffset.x * 2.0f + pageWidth) / (pageWidth * 2.0f));

self.pageControl.currentPage = page;

NSInteger firstPage = page - 1;
NSInteger lastPage = page + 1;

for (NSInteger i=0; i<firstPage; i++) {
    [self purgePage:i];
}

for (NSInteger i=firstPage; i<=lastPage; i++) {
    [self loadPage:i];
}

for (NSInteger i=lastPage+1; i<self.array_pageContent.count; i++) {
    [self purgePage:i];
}
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
[self loadVisiblePages];
}
```

And the hierarchy for storyboard is 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove Container View From Views hierarchy your scroll will be work.

and replcae your viewDidLoad() metod from following code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGFloat width = 0.0;

    self.array_pageContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    CallViewController *objGameReviewPageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CallViewController"];
    [self addChildViewController:objGameReviewPageContentViewController];
    width = objGameReviewPageContentViewController.view.frame.size.width;
    [self.scrollViewContent addSubview:objGameReviewPageContentViewController.view];

//    UIView * view = objGameReviewPageContentViewController.view;




    HomeViewController *objHomeViewController= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];

    CGRect frame = objHomeViewController.view.frame;
    frame.origin.x = objGameReviewPageContentViewController.view.frame.size.width;
    objHomeViewController.view.frame = frame;
    width += frame.size.width;

    NSLog(@"%f",width);

    [self addChildViewController:objHomeViewController];
    [self.scrollViewContent addSubview:objHomeViewController.view];
//    UIView * view1 = objHomeViewController.view;





    GroupViewController *objGroupViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GroupViewController"];

    frame = objGroupViewController.view.frame;
    frame.origin.x = objGameReviewPageContentViewController.view.frame.size.width*2;
    objGroupViewController.view.frame = frame;
    width += frame.size.width;

    NSLog(@"%f",width);

    [self addChildViewController:objGroupViewController];
    [self.scrollViewContent addSubview:objGroupViewController.view];
//    [self addChildViewController:objGroupViewController];
//    UIView * view2 = objGroupViewController.view;




    CallenderViewController *objCallenderViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CallenderViewController"];

    frame = objCallenderViewController.view.frame;
    frame.origin.x = objGameReviewPageContentViewController.view.frame.size.width*3;
    objCallenderViewController.view.frame = frame;
    width += frame.size.width;

    NSLog(@"%f",width);

    [self addChildViewController:objCallenderViewController];
    [self.scrollViewContent addSubview:objCallenderViewController.view];

//    [self addChildViewController:objCallenderViewController];
//    UIView * view3 = objGroupViewController.view;




    CasesViewController *objCasesViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CasesViewController"];

    frame = objCasesViewController.view.frame;
    frame.origin.x = objGameReviewPageContentViewController.view.frame.size.width*4;
    objCasesViewController.view.frame = frame;
    width += frame.size.width;

    NSLog(@"%f",width);

    [self addChildViewController:objCasesViewController];
    [self.scrollViewContent addSubview:objCasesViewController.view];

//    [self addChildViewController:objCasesViewController];
//    UIView * view4 = objGroupViewController.view;




    [self.scrollViewContent setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [self.scrollViewContent setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [self.scrollViewContent setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:YES];
    [self.scrollViewContent setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [self.scrollViewContent setDelegate:self];

    self.scrollViewContent.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, self.scrollViewContent.frame.size.height);




//        [self.array_pageContent addObject:view];
//        [self.array_pageContent addObject:view1];
//        [self.array_pageContent addObject:view2];
//        [self.array_pageContent addObject:view3];
//        [self.array_pageContent addObject:view4];


//    NSInteger pageCount = self.array_pageContent.count;
//    
//    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
//    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = pageCount;
//    
//    self.mutableArray_pageContentViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < pageCount; ++i) {
//        [self.mutableArray_pageContentViews addObject:[NSNull null]];
//    }

}
```

Comment: Container View is essential 
1. Dynamic Height in UITableView/UICollection
2. It will call life cycle methods of ViewsControllers which are added.

Comment: so why you did not used Collection view instead Container view ?

Comment: CollectionView not instead of Container View. Its inside UIViewController, which will be shown in ContainerView. Height of TableView will be height of Container View automatically.

Comment: yes  i agreed but you can use UICollection which adjust dynamically uicollectionview cell size

Comment: Cell Size only increase height of cell and over all CollectionView, but still it will scroll. I don't want scrolling in collection view, whatever full height will come, it will become height of UIContainerView.

Comment: but i gave answer ov your question and your code not able to add any view in container view check your self.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105559/discussion-between-muhammad-noman-and-sam-shaikh).

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below link. this will solve your problem. Also please don't write too much code, it will be easily done with storyboard.

https://github.com/mluton/EmbeddedSwapping

Comment: Consider more detailed answer, please =)

Comment: I have one container view, and need to add and remove the View Controller when i scroll so can't use the segue and pragmatically add the View Controllers

Comment: @Saood. Please read question properly before you suggest this 3rd party.